# Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobRepositoryTestUtils' type found. With SpringBatchTest Annotation added

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch unit testing using the `@SpringBatchTest` annotation which is supposed to automatically add the beans for `JobLauncherTestUtils` and `JobRepositoryTestUtils`.

Here's the Job configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job getJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                      @Qualifier("flow_master") Flow flowMaster) {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(flowMaster)
                .build().build();
    }
}
```

Here's the Test Class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JobConfiguration.class)
public class SpringBatchTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Before
    public void clearJobExecutions() {
        this.jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyJob() throws Exception {

        JobParameters jobParameters = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();

        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);

        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }

}
```

Problem:

I am getting the error messages:

- *Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobLauncherTestUtils' type found.*

I have cloned some repo examples which are supposed to work but I am getting the same error for all of them.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not share your imports but you are probably mixing imports between junit4 and junit5. I'm not able to reproduce your error. Here is a complete example:

The job configuration class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("Hello world!");
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        }).build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfig.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

The test class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobRepositoryTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyJobConfig.class)
class MyJobConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @BeforeEach
    public void clearJobExecutions() {
        this.jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyJob() throws Exception {
        // given
        JobParameters jobParameters = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();

        // when
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);

        // then
        Assertions.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }

}
```

and the `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so67767525</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so67767525</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- While this has "boot" in the name, it does not bring any Spring Boot feature. -->
    <!-- It is used to manage Spring projects dependencies that are known to work correctly together -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

The test runs successfully without the error you mentioned.

Comment: I've tried your example and I got the same problem. Since it worked for you I understood that something is wrong with my local environnement. After some research on the internet I fixed the problem by changing Severty  of 'Autowiring for Bean Class' in IntelliJ Settings -> Inspections from 'Error' to 'Warning'. Why do IntelliJ show this error for JobLauncherTestUtils and JobRepositoryTestUtils beans particularly?

Comment: `@SpringBatchTest` creates and injects those two beans in the test context. IntelliJ IDEA is not able to intorspect that, hence the error (or warning, depending on the level you've set). You should have mentioned that that error is coming from your IDE, because I understood you were getting it at runtime. But no worries, the most important part is being able to help you.

Comment: Can we use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`